# How to stop background scroll of Fixed element in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using NextJS with tailwind. and I'm creating a drawer, popup and modal with `position: fixed`. so when i implement this and scroll on it the background component will scroll as well. even if the fixed is scrollable when the scroll end the back element starts to scroll. how can I make it stop for the background to be not scrollable and clickable?

```
function Drawer() {
  const toggle = useSelector(selectMenu);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleOnClose = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === "container") dispatch(toggleMenu(!toggle));
  };
  return (
    <div
      id="container"
      onClick={handleOnClose}
      className={`md:hidden h-full w-full backdrop-blur-sm fixed ${
        !toggle && "hidden"
      }`}
    >
      <div
        className={`${
          toggle ? " translate-x-0" : "translate-x-full"
        } md:hidden fixed h-screen w-3/4 ease-in-out duration-300 bg-white z-50 bottom-0 top-0 right-0 flex flex-col px-4 py-3 space-y-5 shadow-2xl`}
      >
        <Link
          href="/"
          className="cursor-pointer flex px-2 space-x-4"
          onClick={() => dispatch(toggleMenu(!toggle))}
        >
          <HomeModernIcon className="h-6 w-6 text-black" />
          <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        </Link>
        <div className=" h-[1px] w-full bg-gray-600" />
        <Link
          href="/clients"
          className="cursor-pointer flex px-2 space-x-4"
          onClick={() => dispatch(toggleMenu(!toggle))}
        >
          <TruckIcon className="h-6 w-6 text-black" />
          <h1>Clients</h1>
        </Link>
        <div className=" h-[1px] w-full bg-gray-600" />
        <Link
          href="/employee"
          className="cursor-pointer flex px-2 space-x-4"
          onClick={() => dispatch(toggleMenu(!toggle))}
        >
          <PuzzlePieceIcon className="h-6 w-6 text-black" />
          <h1>Employee</h1>
        </Link>
        <div className=" h-[1px] w-full bg-gray-600" />
        <Link
          href="/services"
          className="cursor-pointer flex px-2 space-x-4"
          onClick={() => dispatch(toggleMenu(!toggle))}
        >
          <WrenchIcon className="h-6 w-6 text-black" />
          <h1>Services</h1>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `Modal` component add this `useEffect`. since you are using `tailwind-css`, add `overflow-hidden` className to the body element

```
useEffect(() => {
    // this will disable the scroll if our back page was scrollable
    document.body.classList.add("overflow-hidden");
    // when you close the modal, remove this class 
    return () => {
      document.body.classList.remove("overflow-hidden");
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: i accepted the answer and tested it later. but when i use this the background becomes un scrollable indefinitely. i used it with conditional and the first problem all over again

Comment: did you return properly ` return () => {
      document.body.classList.remove("overflow-hidden");
    }; `

Comment: assuming modal component is a separate component, you add this `useEffect` inside that component.

Comment: it needed the dependency injection (argument) in the use Effect